# What will be sql query to print all rows from multiple table with same id table?

Tags: mysql, sql

For Example, I have 2 tables first table has custid,custname and second table has custid,cust multiple mobile numbers......I want to print custname and cust mobile numbers using custid then what will be my sql query?

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: Hint: `...INNER JOIN ... ON <table1>.custid = <table2>.custid ...` or `... INNER JOIN ... USING(custid) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply JOINS in multiple table relationship. A simple example is a user and yours phones:

> ```
> TABLE USER : usr_id, attributes...
> TABLE PHONE : phn_id, attributes, fk_usr_id
> ```

a query to view the phones of the user:

```
SELECT * FROM user as usr 
INNER JOIN phone as phn ON phn.fk_usr_id = usr.usr_id
```

All of this in the documentation.
Greats